# Column appearing blank after changing field name in DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

I changed the name of a field in an automation/query and there were other queries that used this specific field.  I changed the name of this field for all the other DE's and inside their own automations too.

FOr some reason the field is now blank even though in query studio it shows data - should I delete this field and insert it again into the data extension?  The data type is also correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Found my solution, I changed the DE to another DE then reverted it back to the original and it worked

Comment: You should resave the query in the future